# How to sum the digits in text in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, text-parsing, office-2007

I have an Excel sheet
[image]

The requirement is to sum the digits in the cells in column 'C' and put the value in the corresponding cell in column 'B' (in my example 0.25 + 1 + 0.25 + 1 = 2.5).

The values in Column 'C' could change. The requirement is to update the value in 'B' as soon as the cell in column 'C' changes.

I did ask the creator to change to text and numbers in two different columns but that is not acceptable because of the standard template.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be achieved, without altering the text in the cell, using a Macro.
I have to admit, the implementation will be a little retarded, since you need to do a few things.

1 -  Tokenize the entire cell content, and store the tokens into a string array.

There is a problem already. The text located inside the cell is grossly inconsistent.  You have -250 ms, - 250 ms, - 1sec, - 1 sec. Due to this, you are going to need to check for each instance. Therefore, you cannot just check if the value is a number, you need to check all the permutations that your team members have conveniently provided for you.

The best way to do this would be to check against Regular Expressions.  Therefore, #2 should be:

2 -  Check each value to see if it matches to one of many 4 Regular Expressions.

3 -  Depending on the Regex it matches with, extract the numerical value.

a) If simply a value (ie->250), check if ms or sec proceeds the value.  IF ms, divide the number by 1000.  If sec, leave number as is.  Add number to total.
b)  If a number preceded by a dash(-), remove dash, and repeat step a)
c)  If a number followed by letters, remove letters and repeat step a)
d)  If a number followed by a period, do nothing. This is a bullet point.

Comment: Thanks Jon
I finally managed to convince them to put the values in a consistent manner. So, now the values are put as '- xx ms' or '- xx sec' (made my life a little easier)
I implemented the rest of the logic as suggested in your answer.
Works great now ... Thanks !!!